# Install PHP OPCACHE on Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install PHP OPCACHE on my Amazon Linux EC2 instance but I am getting some errors related to conflict. The version of PHP running on my EC2 is PHP Version 5.3.29. More details can be seen here [Info](http://yunus.web5050.info/info.php)

I am trying to install it via SSH using Putty. I am using the following command,

```
sudo yum install -y php54-pecl-apc
```

OR

```
sudo yum install php55-opcache
```

I still get the error. [Error](http://yunus.web5050.info/images/error.png)
[image]
How can I install OPCACHE? Am I doing any other mistake?

Comment: Hi, I'm not going to click on a link on your website, please include the actual errors in your question or upload your images to SO.

Comment: I edited my post to include the error I get. Please review it once.

Comment: When I try `sudo yum install php-opcache`, I get this error
`Error - PHP-56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amaz1.x86_64`,
`Error - PHP-56-common conflicts with php-commom-5.3.29-1.8.amaz1.x86_64`

Comment: I am not sure which version of OPCACHE should I install which will work nicely.

Comment: can you update your PHP? PHP 5.3 is deprecated

Comment: I updated to php7.0. and everything is working now. I installed the OPcache 7.0 as well. Thank you so much. You guys were really helpful.